# Finding the $T$-invariant subspaces of an operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear operator given by $$T\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Determine all the $T$-invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I am having trouble finding a result in my textbook that illuminates on how to do this process.

The section in my text preceding this problem first introduces the concept of a linear operator $f(T)$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial, and then defines the order ideal $$\mathrm{ann}(T,v) := \{f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]: f(T)(v)=0 \}$$ and the annihilator ideal $$\mathrm{ann}(T) := \{f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]: f(T)(v) = 0 \text{ for every } v \in V \}.$$ The textbook then proves that both of the ideals contain polynomials other than the $0$ polynomial. It then defines the minimal polynomials of both $\mathrm{ann}(T,v)$ and $\mathrm{ann}(T)$, which are the unique monic polynomials of least degree.

The textbook then bombards us with more definitions, defining $T$-invariant subspaces, eigenvectors, eigenvalues, and then $T$-cylic subspaces $$\langle T,v \rangle := \{ f(T)(v): f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]\}$$

The section then concludes with a theorem proving that $T$-cylic subspaces are $T$-invariant, that each $T$-invariant subspaces $W$ containing the generator $v$ of a $T$-cyclic subspace $\langle T,v \rangle$ also contains $\langle T,v \rangle$ and that the degree $d$ of the minimal polynomial of $\mathrm{ann}(T,v)$ is equal to the dimension of $\langle T,v \rangle$ and that $v, T(v),\ldots,T^{d-1}(v)$ is a basis of $\langle T,v \rangle$.

How do we determine all the $T$-invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$? I am not sure how to do to it with the given information in the section. Do we first find the minimal polynomial of the operator with respect to a basis vector and then somehow relate that to the $T$-cyclic subspace? Any help appreciated

Comment: The $T$-invariant subspace is the eigenspace of $T$, i.e. the span of eigenvectors of $T$.